# SOS Name2EE only showing Module and Assembly information

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sos

I just discovered [SOS Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) and am trying it out with a stupid hello world console app in Visual Studio 2010.  I have enabled debugging unmanaged code and executed `.load sos` on my project properties.  However, when I do `!Name2EE App.exe!Program` I only see the Module and Assembly info.  I don't see the MethodTable or anything else:

```
!Name2EE App.exe!Program
Module:      001c2e9c
Assembly:    App.exe
```

Can anyone shed some light on why I'm not seeing the rest of the info?

Answer (score 2):

Try using actual type name including namespace:

```
0:000> !Name2EE HelloWorld!MyCompany.HelloWorld.Program
Module:      00182e9c
Assembly:    HelloWorld.exe
Token:       02000006
MethodTable: 00183888
EEClass:     00181794
Name:        MyCompany.HelloWorld.Program
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a filename with extension, separate the module from the type.
!name2ee app.exe Program
-OR-
!name2ee app!MyApp.Program

Also, as the previous answer indicated, always use the FULL type name.